# Grub menu not appearing after reinstall and boot repair

Tags: boot, grub2

I reinstalled Ubuntu (it was working right) and now the Grub menu is not appearing. I've used the Boot Repair tool too, it just shows a black screen and the underline flashing.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5717138/

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried it with command in terminal?  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
update-grub
```

if this does not help, then try

```
apt-get install --reinstall grub
```

then

```
grub-install
```

and finally at end

```
update-grub
```

this should work.