# Unable to open any of the disk except the one in which ubuntu is installed

Tags: dual-boot, windows, mount, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu a few days back on my laptop with Windows 8 previously installed.
now whenever I start my laptop I don't have any option to go to Windows and I have to use Ubuntu only. But in Ubuntu also I am unable to access any of my personal drives. It says "Error in mounting" with a long message.

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/302099/280083) will help with the mounting issue, but it should solve the booting issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us this "long message". We can't help if we don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 never actually shuts down... it always hibernates. And in the process the disks hibernate along with it and become unaccessible by other operating systems. That is why you get that long message. To prevent this, when windows 8 boots(i.e. after your problem is fixed) type "lid" in search and then choose "change what closing the lid does". Then unselect "turn on fast startup" and then reboot your laptop. You should now be able to access your hard disks from ubuntu. Better way is to dual boot ubuntu and windows 7 since in windows 7, when it shuts down, it does not hibernate, it REALLY shuts down.
And I think for the booting issue, solution by sclev in the comments is helpful.